# Sharing project in Homegroup

Tags: eclipse

I have a laptop and a desktop, and I want to share projects I develop with eclipse between them. I want them to sync *automatically*.

I tried using Windows Homegroup sharing, but it doesnt work so well because the project path's are different in each computer, so each computer's `.project` file has to be different...

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this is strictly a programming question, but you might want to take a look at [dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/). It should allow you to sync your files without any issues.

Comment: I have read about it, I think ill try it. Although it is said that the synced files are only in the "dropbox" folder, I want them to go automatically to the project folder.. But I could write a code that will do this transfer.

Comment: I think you should be able to set your Project wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

why not just sync source codes, without eclipse settings? 
then you have many ways to do it.

e.g.

version control repository

softlink to your mount point

online storage with sync feature

...

Comment: I thought about google code and git, but these are for open source projects, aren't they?

Comment: bitbucket allow free user to have private repositories. And you don't have to make source control online, if you just want to sync. you can have your own repository.